# Show results of link below link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have no idea if this is poosible, but I'm trying to do something and need some direction.

I have a link that sends a command to an IP camera for example:http://www.mydomain.com/cgi-bin/cmd/encoder?VIDEO_RESOLUTION=N1280x720 when I click on the link it simply opens in a new tab and shows me 1 or 2 lines of code like: "SUCCESS"

I would like to make this result come out right next to where I click the link. Is this possible? If yes, any direction would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: yes thats possible. You could use JavaScript or even jQuery to load the content of the other page into any html-element embedded on your page.

Comment: Ajax is what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript and not Java. JavaScript compares to Java like Apple to PineApple. They just have one common Part in the name.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach lol thanks... I like your analogy too, and I'm slowly learning.

Comment: No Problem. It is a common mistake. Lots of people are confused by the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use AJAX to do it.
This can be easily done with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("YOUR BUTTON CSS SELECTOR").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "your_validator_url",
    }).done(function() {
      $( this ).append("SUCCESS");
    });
});
});
```